# Rails 3.2 Form Validation Exclude an Exact String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

,I need to validate a form field so it cannot be a specific string.  For example if someone inputs "hello" into a text field and submits the form, how can I throw an error saying that particular string is not allowed?  Is there a way to avoid doing this on the client side with javascript so I can keep the feel consistent?

```
validates_presence of :field_name, #condition here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass custom validation

```
INVALID_STRING = %W(string1, string2, string3, ... )
def valid_field_name    // valid_name
  if INVALID_STRING.include?(self.field_name)
    errors[:base] << "field_name you enter that not valid." unless self.field_name.blank?
  end
end
```

call this method

```
 validate:valid_field_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom validations in rails are pretty simple here is an example of throwing an error on an attribute "name" if it is not included in an array of strings.

```
WHITELIST = %w(string1 string2 otherstring)

validate :name_is_ok

def name_is_ok
  unless WHITELIST.include? name 
    errors[:name] << "is not valid" 
  end
end
```